# Using VBA code to add a row based on change of value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a row with formula from above row included based on the value change to the first row cell A2.

The code I use now will add a row only if I manually put data in first row cell A2. Since I have a formula in the cell it Nevers registers a change so does not add a row.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    'Test if change is in column A and only one cell changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A")) Is Nothing And _
            Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
           
        Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown      'Insert row below data entry
   
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to use `Worksheet_Calculate`. The change event doesn't fire when values change due to formula recalc.

Comment: I thank you for the help but being  a little new to this I am not sure what has to be changed to have it go to calculate. Thanks again

Comment: You could start with the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)), as well as similar questions on SO.